# How to group by Id across multiple columns with pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a list of dataframes in df

```
dataframe 1:
ID  Name Coupon Description Coupon_Type
100 FXC    2.5  Foo Foo     Fixed
100 FXC    1.5  Foo Foo     Floating
200 MNY    1.0  Man Man     Fixed
300 ABC    2.5  Arm T        Fixed
300 ABC    3.0  Arm M        Fixed
300 ABC    2.5  Arm T        Fixed

dataframe2:
ID  Name Index_Linked
100 FXC  Y
300 ABC  N
```

Trying to get a resultant dataframe like this

```
ID  Name Coupon        Description    Coupon_Type      Index_Linked
100 FXC [2.5,1.5]      Foo Foo        [Fixed, Floating]  Y
200 MNY 1.0            Man Man        Fixed
300 ABC [2.5,3.0]      [Arm T, Arm M] Fixed              N
```

If I try

```
df_final=pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True)
```

I get

```
ID  Name Coupon Description Coupon_Type Index_Linked
100 FXC    2.5  Foo Foo     Fixed
100 FXC    1.5  Foo Foo     Floating
100 FXC                                    Y
200 MNY    1.0  Man Man     Fixed
300 ABC    2.5  Arm T       Fixed
300 ABC    3.0  Arm M       Fixed
300 ABC    2.5  Arm T       Fixed
300 ABC                                    N
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let us try

```
out = df1.groupby(['ID','Name']).agg(lambda x : set(x)).reset_index().merge(df2,how='left')
Out[86]: 
    ID Name      Coupon   Description        Coupon_Type Index_Linked
0  100  FXC  {1.5, 2.5}      {FooFoo}  {Floating, Fixed}            Y
1  200  MNY       {1.0}      {ManMan}            {Fixed}          NaN
2  300  ABC  {2.5, 3.0}  {ArmT, ArmM}            {Fixed}            N
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by `groupby()` method,`agg()` method and `merge()` method:

```
resultdf=df1.groupby(['ID','Name'],as_index=False).agg(lambda x : list(set(x))[0] if len(list(set(x)))==1 else list(set(x))).merge(df2,how='left')
```

Now if you print `resultdf` you will get your desired output:

```
    ID      Name    Coupon      Description     Coupon_Type         Index_Linked
0   100     FXC     [1.5, 2.5]  Foo Foo         [Fixed, Floating]       Y
1   200     MNY     1.0         Man Man         Fixed                   NaN
2   300     ABC     [2.5, 3.0]  [Arm T, Arm M]  Fixed                   N
```